# Is it alright to delete everything from my Local Disk (G:) drive?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I recently hooked up an old Local Disk from one of my old computers to my new one to increase disk space. However, the old one is full of junk I don't want or need, and Disk Cleaner won't do anything. If, say, I select all the files in that disk and delete them all, will anything bad happen? I haven't installed anything onto it for my new computer, so it shouldn't affect it, right? And if I clean it out and install something on it, would that program still work?

Answer (score 3):

Do a right click on the drive in Windows Explorer and select `Format`

[image]

to clean the disk completely. Now store data on it as on every other drive.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting everything via File Explorer, your best bet is to start Disk Manager (diskmgmt.msc), delete the partition(s), and create a new partition.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

If you are certain you no longer need any files from that hard drive which came from your old computer, then you can perform that @magicandre1981 said and format it.

This way, your drive will be emptied and can be used just like you would any other new drive you install in your computer.

Formatting it will also be a much **faster** option than selecting all the files and deleting them.

Comment: This is essentially just commentary on the other answers and is not really an answer in its own right. It would be better as a comment on one of the existing answer rather than an answer itself.